# rendering form to two partials in different folders in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `_form` partial for `surv_rdsap_xrefs` controller.

I want to keep the `error` methods in the `form` and the `fields` are rendering from two different folders. one is `condtion/rdsap_xrefs/_surv_rdsap_xrefs` and another is `section/condition/_question`.

### _form:

```
<%= form_for(@enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref) do |f| %>
        <% if @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors.count, "error") %>:</h2>
            <ul>
              <% @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>

        <div class="left">
          <%= render 'section/condition/_question' %>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <%= render 'condition/rdsap_xref/surv_rdsap_xref' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Now, i got the error of undefined method of `f` in the partials. How to partial these two for the same form. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="left">
      <%= render 'section/condition/_question', f: f %>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <%= render 'condition/rdsap_xref/surv_rdsap_xref', f: f %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

As in partials there must be a variable `f` to which you have to assign some value. Thats why I have assigned the `f` of `form_for` into the partial variable `f`

Answer (score 2):

for your error you must pass locals f in your partial so that

write this, for **section/condition/_question**

```
<%= render 'section/condition/_question', f: f %>
```

and for **condition/rdsap_xref/surv_rdsap_xref** this

```
<%= render 'condition/rdsap_xref/surv_rdsap_xref', f: f %>
```